# The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Align widget

Tags: flutter

I am develop a translation app and now I complete the query of translate result showing UI. When the flutter UI was rendering, shows error like this:

```
I/flutter (24035): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (24035): │ ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════
I/flutter (24035): │ The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
I/flutter (24035): │ Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
I/flutter (24035): │ The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData
I/flutter (24035): │ of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up
I/flutter (24035): │ to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.
I/flutter (24035): │ Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong
I/flutter (24035): │ ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are
I/flutter (24035): │ placed directly inside Flex widgets.
I/flutter (24035): │ The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Align widget.
I/flutter (24035): │ The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the
I/flutter (24035): │ incompatible parent data was:
I/flutter (24035): │   Column ← Expanded ← Align ← Padding ← ConstrainedBox ←
I/flutter (24035): │ Container ← _RawMouseRegion ← MouseRegion ← WordTranslationView ←
I/flutter (24035): │ Column ← ⋯
I/flutter (24035): │ 
I/flutter (24035): │ When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (24035): │ #0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5835:11)
I/flutter (24035): │ #1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5851:6)
I/flutter (24035): │ #2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5873:7)
```

where is going wrong and what should I do to avoid this problem? This is my code of `WordTranslationView`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../includes.dart';

class WordTranslationView extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextTranslation wordTranslation;

  const WordTranslationView(
    this.wordTranslation, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WordTranslationViewState createState() => _WordTranslationViewState();
}

class _WordTranslationViewState extends State<WordTranslationView> {
  bool _isHovered = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (event) {
          _isHovered = true;
          setState(() {});
        },
        onExit: (event) {
          _isHovered = false;
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: 40,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 7,
            bottom: 7,
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, left: 0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Color(0xff80838a).withOpacity(0.6),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Translation',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff80838a),
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    width: 100,
                    child: Flexible(
                        child: SelectableText.rich(
                      TextSpan(
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(text: widget.wordTranslation.text),
                        ],
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(height: 1.4, fontSize: 16),
                    ))),
                if ((widget.wordTranslation.audioUrl ?? '').isNotEmpty && _isHovered)
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: SoundPlayButton(
                      audioUrl: widget.wordTranslation.audioUrl,
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The widget [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) can only be used in a [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html), [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) or in a [Flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html).
To fix your error you have to remove your `Expanded` which is wrapped around your `Column`.